# Creating required script

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-scripts

My question is about select statement. I have a table called **test1** and the values in it. Here my script for creating the table, and inserting values:

```
create table test1(id number, pc number, pe number);
insert into test1 values(12,0,900); 
insert into test1 values(12,0,901);
insert into test1 values(12,0,902);
insert into test1 values(12,91,900);
insert into test1 values(12,0,1);
insert into test1 values(12,91,900); 
insert into test1 values(12,91,901); 
insert into test1 values(12,91,900);
insert into test1 values(12,91,5);
insert into test1 values(13,0,900);
insert into test1 values(12,0,20); 
insert into test1 values(12,1,1);
insert into test1 values(12,0,900);
insert into test1 values(13,91,900); 
insert into test1 values(13,91,901); 
insert into test1 values(13,91,902); 
insert into test1 values(13,0,902);
insert into test1 values(13,91,201); 
insert into test1 values(13,91,202);
insert into test1 values(13,91,20);
insert into test1 values(13,0,900);
insert into test1 values(13,0,900); 
commit;
```

My question is how can I select the **Id**s from **test1** table that the **pc** column contains only **0 or 91** and **pe** column contains only **20, 201, 202, 900, 901 or 902**. So **Id**s like **13**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that count of satisfying rows is equal to count(*):

```sql
select id
from test1
group by id
having 
   count(*) = count(case when pc in (0,91) and pe in (20, 201, 202, 900, 901, 902) then 1 end)
```

Comment: Thanks,It worked, but I didnot understand actually. Please can you explain ?

Comment: Oups I got it @Sayan Malakshinov . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sql for you

```
select id from test1 where pc in (0,91) and pe in (20, 201, 202, 900, 901, 902);
```

Comment: No bro. What if you do not know exact ID? In your case if I just gave where id = 13 it is enough, even if you do not specify pc and pe columns.

Comment: Try this 
select id from test1 where pc in (0,91) and pe in (20, 201, 202, 900, 901, 902)

Comment: your second comment is also not right it will give us output id = 12, because in test1 table also have a row for example id =12 and pc =0 and pe=20.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A, B from(
    select decode(pc,0,91,id,0) A, decode(pe,20,201,202,900,901,902,id,0) B from test1
) where A <> B;
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct c from(select decode(id,12,0,13,13) c from(select a.id from test1 a,test1 b
where a.pc=b.pc and b.pe=a.pe and a.id=b.id)where 1=1)
where c=13;